# You tried to execute a query that does not include the specified expression

Tags: sql, database, ms-access, ms-access-2010

Sorry if the question seems low level but I was never formally taught Access and everything I know I've just sort of muddled into.

Basically, I am trying to make a crosstab query where the column and row headers are both the names of airports that the charity airline I'm interning for flies to.

I'm trying to make it where the column and rows are both airport names and the value is the distance between the two calculated through the latitude and longitude (both contained within the same table as the airport names).

I'm calculating distance with this little expression `[Sqr((Lat2-Lat1)^2+(Long2-Long1)^2)]` but when I put that in I get the error message:

> You tried to execute a query that does not include the specified expression.

Ultimately my expression looks like this:

```
Sqr(([Airstrip List January 2017]![Latitude]-[Airstrip List January 2017]![Latitude])^2+([Airstrip List January 2017]![Longitude]-[Airstrip List January 2017]![Longitude])^2)
```

I think what I'm doing wrong is I'm telling Access to look in the table to find the lat and long whereas I should be telling it to look based of what the header and columns are.

Sorry if this seemed very rambly but I am very new to this kind of stuff... Any and all help appreciated.

Comment: Surely `([Airstrip List January 2017]![Latitude]-[Airstrip List January 2017]![Latitude])^2` will always be `0` ? Ditto for the long.

Comment: That's what I'm saying. I'm trying to get it to select based off the column and row of the query, not off the tables as I have it, but I don't know how to do that.

Comment: Try to describe your table structure a little more, and clarify your end goal and someone should be able to help you better.

Comment: So... I have one table, "Airstrip List January 2017". Within that list is the names of airports and their latitude and longitude split into two different columns entitled "Latitude" and "Longitude". I am trying to create a crosstab query for showing distances between any 2 airfields. Where the column and row headers will be Airport Name and then the value will be the distance between the two using the formula posted above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your crosstab query needs to be set up as follows:

1. Add the table `Airstrip List January 2017` into the query twice, but do not have any join between them.
2. Give the two tables aliases (show Properties and then when you click on a table the first Property is the Alias). Call one of them `Start` and the other one `End`
3. Put the airfield name from the `Start` table as the first column in the grid. Set `Total` as `Group By` and `Crosstab` as `Row Heading`.
4. Put the airfield name from the `End` table as the second column in the grid. Set `Total` as `Group By` and `Crosstab` as `Column Heading`.
5. Set the third grid column to `Distance: Sqr(([Start].[Latitude]-[End].[Latitude])^2+([Start].[Longitude]-[End].[Longitude])^2)`  with the `Total` set as `Sum` and the `Crosstab` set as `Value`

Run the query!

Comment: I tried this and got the error, "Data type mismatch in criteria expression".
I'm gonna fiddle around and see if I can't get it to work. Definitely a step in the right direction though... Thank you!

Comment: Is it something to do with the fact that there will be null when comparing 2 of the same airfields that's stopping it from working?

Comment: There shouldn't be any criteria expression (unless you've added any in yourself that aren't in my original answer). On the query grid I am only putting entries in the Field, Table, Total and Crosstab rows. I did this myself with some dummy data and didn't get this error. Also, you won't get null when comparing two airfields the same, you will get zero. If you're still having problems, post your query (either an image or preferably the SQL) and I'll take a look.

Comment: There's nothing in the criteria, but I'm still getting the issue. This is what it all looks like. https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/29273701/Access.png

Comment: I think you might have nulls in your Latitude or Longitude data. Try adding these four columns to your grid (Lat and Long from both tables), setting the `Total` to `Where` and the `Criteria` to `Is Not Null` (all on the same Criteria row).

Comment: I think I've found the issue. Might it be that the lats/longs include a prefix of E in longitude and N/S for latitude? I assume that is the issue? Should I make the latitudes positive for north and negative for south?

Comment: Yes, that would do it. Correct all your data to remove all the E, W, N, S characters and make S and W numbers negative. Then change your lat/long field definitions in the table to Number (Double). You cannot sum alphanumeric entries, which is why you're getting the 'Data type mismatch' error.